# Numba jitclass with function input

Tags: python, numba

I'm working on developing an adaptive rejection sampler in Numba. I'd like to use a class to implement it since I think it'll make the code a lot cleaner, and I see that classes are supported in Numba. My class would be a lot more general/useful if it could take functions as input, i.e. the log pdf of the distribution I want to sample from. Is there any way to do that?  The alternative I guess is to define the log pdf equations in the class definition itself.

Why do I want to do this?  The sampler will be used as part of a Gibbs sampling scheme, so speed ups in each sampling step are crucial. I have to simulate from a distribution I know only up to a normalizing constant, and adaptive rejection sampling is a general technique that will help me sample without needing to know this normalizing constant. There is a python implementation of an adaptive rejection sampler floating around stack overflow, but it's too slow for my purposes. It also randomly breaks for some reason on some simulated data that it should work on. I've had luck with numba on other parts of my project, including a greater than 100x speed up on one part of the Gibbs sampler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numba functions cannot take functions as input arguments. The official docs recommend possibly using closures in a function factory as a workaround in some cases:

http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/faq.html#can-i-pass-a-function-as-an-argument-to-a-jitted-function

Copying the code example from the above link in case the url ever becomes invalid:

```
def make_f(g):
    # Note: a new f() is compiled each time make_f() is called!
    @jit(nopython=True)
    def f(x):
        return g(x) + g(-x)
    return f

f = make_f(my_g_function)
result = f(1)
```

Not sure if this would work in your particular case though. I think defining the functions you want as class methods would be a better strategy, although without a code example, I'm just guessing.